# PHP cannot verify if directory exists

Tags: php

I am going crazy with this one

I have this folders and files structure

- /

  - /projects

    - /mytest

      - /install

        - /index.php
      - /product
  - /resources

So, inside my install/index.php file I am trying to verify if /product folder does exist. I know that the folder exists, but looks like PHP doesn't. My code:

```
if(file_exists('../../mytest/product') && is_dir('../../mytest/product')) {
    echo 'Folder exists!';
} else {
    echo 'PHP is blind or something!';
}
```

Maybe I am very tired, but I just cannot figure out what is wrong. Some rested minds here maybe will see the problem. Thanks!

Comment: What do getcwd() return?

Comment: Debug with `realpath('../../mytest/product');`

Comment: Don't forget about directory permissions. PHP may simply not see that directory.

Comment: Run clearstatcache() since the result of these functions are stored in the stat cache.

Comment: Are you running this php file locally or as an http request? The latter can mess with how the directories are viewed, and how permissions are read.

Comment: Also, I assume that you're running index.php raw, and not as an include in another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With your current directory structure:**

```
/
    /projects
        /mytest
            /install
                /index.php
            /product
    /resources
```

**The following code works just fine:**

```
<?php
if(file_exists('../product') && is_dir('../product')) {
    echo 'Folder exists!';
} else {
    echo 'PHP is blind or something!';
}
?>
```

**As does your current code:**

```
<?php
if(file_exists('../../mytest/product') && is_dir('../../mytest/product')) {
    echo 'Folder exists!';
} else {
    echo 'PHP is blind or something!';
}
?>
```

Both solutions outputted "**Folder exists!**", so the issue is related with folder permissions.

---

**You need to confirm:**

- Owner for that folder

*Remember that the owner of the directory has to be the same of the script user, otherwise this function will always return false when PHP is running in* [safe_mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php)..

- [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)

*Limit the files that can be opened by PHP to the specified directory-tree..*